# How to install rspec when it has to be in both test and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to specify a version of rspec to be installed, but in order to use it, you have to install it as:

```
gem 'rspec', group: [:test, :development]
```

If you only put it in test it will tell you it cannot require such file rspec in bla bla bla.

So, I am curious as to how you would install rspec at say version 3.0 for group test and development

Comment: whats the problem in `gem 'rspec', group: [:test, :development]`? Is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec', '3.0.0'
end
```